# Java Filter list object with Recursive Children

Tags: java, list, stream, recursive-datastructures

Given this obj.

```
public class Menu {

private String id;
private String matchCode;
private List<Menu> children;

//getters and setters

/**
   * Flattened funcition to recursive children list
   */
  public Stream<Menu> flatenned() {
    return Stream.concat(
          Stream.of(this),
          children.stream().flatMap(Menu::flatenned));
  }

}
```

I need to filter a List and remove all items (parent) that doesn't match to a given matchCode. I also need to filter all the children (at this point there can be 'N' children) by the same field (matchCode)

Since the children is a recursive list structure I found that the method flatenned can help achieve this. ([see reference](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2015/03/04/walking-recursive-data-structures-using-java-8-streams/))

So far I have this.

```
private List<Menu> filterByMatchRoleCode(List<Menu> menuList) {
    return menuList.stream()
      .filter(p -> "string".matches(p.getMatchCode()))
      .map(c -> c.getChildren()
            .stream()
            .map(o -> o.flatenned()
                  .map(Menu::getMatchCode)
                  .filter(v -> "string".matches(v)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
  }
```

this method filterByMatchRoleCode gives error trying to return the value.

Hope someone can point what I'm missing or can give me a different approach.

Comment: If a child's `matchCode` matches do you want to remove the parent or do you want to remove the child from parent's `children` list?

Comment: if parent obj matches the string I want to keep the object then I should proceed to to the same with the children, if matchCode in the children does not match it should be removed.
if a parent obj does not match with the given string I should remove the parent and I dont care about the children since the obj parent was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think could be simpler.

```
    private List<Menu> filterByMatchRoleCode(List<Menu> menuList) {
        return menuList.stream()
                .peek( x -> x.setChildren( filterByMatchRoleCode(x.children)))
                .filter(p -> "string".matches(p.getMatchCode()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: work as expected, and also filters all the nested children regardless of their position